# Discord.PY: Variable no toma valor asignado dentro de una función

Tags: python, async-await, discord.py

estoy creando un bot en Python, he logrado obtener la ID del canal que un usuario mencione:

```
canals = "No especificado"

async def canal(ctx, canal: discord.TextChannel):
    canals = bot.get_channel(canal.id)
```

El problema llega cuando quiero, en otra función, mandar un mensaje al canal cuyo ID conseguimos,
esto es lo que intenté:

```
async def mensaje(ctx):
await canals.send("mensaje")
```

También probé añadiendo canals al lado de ctx, pero resulta en 2 errores, uno cuando pruebo sin canals, y otro cuando si lo pongo:

**Sin**: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send'

**Con**: canals is a required argument that is missing.

Probé realizando un print debajo de la función para obtener la id del canal, y me da la ID del canal correctamente, a lo que supuse que la función para enviar el mensaje está intentando enviarlo al primer valor de la variable, o sea, el "No especificado" en vez del segundo, el de la ID, pero no se como hacer para que tome el segundo valor, cualquier ayuda me sería fantástica, gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes un problema de *scope*. En la función

```
async def canal(ctx, canal: discord.TextChannel):
    canals = bot.get_channel(canal.id)
```

la variable `canals` es local a la función; no es la misma variable `canals` que has declarado fuera.

Mira este ejemplo, que reproduce tu código:

```
canals = "No especificado"

def cambia_canal(canal):
    canals = canal

print(canals) => "No especificado"
cambia_canal("deportes")
print(canals) => "No especificado"
```

Si quieres cambiar la variable global, tienes que declararla como tal:

```
canals = "No especificado"

def cambia_canal(canal):
    global canals
    canals = canal

print(canals) => "No especificado"
cambia_canal("deportes")
print(canals) => "deportes"
```

y tu función debería lucir así:

```
async def canal(ctx, canal: discord.TextChannel):
    global canals
    canals = bot.get_channel(canal.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

segun entiendo (me corriges por favor)

```
canals = "No especificado"
```

La variable canals, la estas usando como una variable global. Si es asi. En python debes usar la palabra reservada ***global*** para hacer referencia a un variable global.
Por ejemplo:

```
__variable_global__ = "No especificado"

async def canal(ctx, canal: discord.TextChannel):

    global __variable_global__
    __variable_global__ = bot.get_channel(canal.id)
```

De esta manera Python sabra que te estas refiriendo a una variable global cuando encuentre esa variable. De lo contrario la tomara como una variable local y solo tomara valores dentro de la función.

Comment: No creo que usar `__` alrededor del nombre de la variable sea seguro. Python tiene muchas de sus palabras reservadas rodeadas de `__`, las siguientes se crean al inicio de todo modulo de Python: `['__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']`

Comment: Gran observación @Dante_S. El uso de guiones bajos, es debido a la sugerencia del PEP-8 [ python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#global-variable-names ] Los módulos que están diseñados para usarse a través de from M import * deben usar el mecanismo __ all __ para evitar la exportación de variables globales, o usar la convención anterior de prefijar dichos globales con un guión bajo (lo que puede hacer para indicar que estos globales son "módulo no público "). Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior, si esto no presenta inconvenientes a futuro en tu código, siéntete en la libertad de hacer caso omiso a ellos.